# Why does the focal length in the camera intrinsics matrix have two dimensions?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

In the [pinhole camera model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model) there is only one focal length which is between the principal point and the camera center.

However, after calculating the camera's intrinsic parameters, the matrix contains

```
(fx,  0,  offsetx,  0,
 0,  fy,  offsety,  0,
 0,   0,  1,        0)
```

Is this because the pixels of the image sensor are not square in x and y?

Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In short: yes. In order to make a mathematical model that can describe a camera with rectangular pixels, you have to introduce two separate focal lengths. I'll quote from the often recommended "[Learning OpenCV](https://books.google.ch/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&lpg=PA373&pg=PA373#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (p. 373) which covers that section pretty well and which I recommend getting if you would like more background on this:

> The focal length fx (for example) is actually the product of the
>   physical focal length of the lens and the size sx of the individual
>   imager elements (this should make sense because sx has units of pixels
>   per millimeter while F has units of millimeters, which means that fx
>   is in the required units of pixels). [...]   It is important to keep
>   in mind, though, that sx and sy cannot be measured directly via any
>   camera calibration process, and neither is the physical focal length F
>   directly measurable. Only the combinations fx = F*sx and fy = F*sy
>   can be derived without actually dismantling the camera and measuring
>   its components directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for "learning opencv" recommendation.

Comment: So, if i want to use F and I have fx and fy available from the camera intrinsics, how do we know the values of sx and sy?

Comment: This statement is actually wrong, and misleading: _"The focal length fx (for example) is actually the product of the physical focal length of the lens and the size sx of the individual imager elements"_.
fx and fy are measured in units of **pixels**, so the correct expression is: fx [pixel] = focal_length [mm] / imager_element_length [mm/pixel].
That is, **it's a division, not a product**. 
It's hard to believe that such an error actually appeared in the Learning OpenCV book, but I don't have a copy around to check... (?).

Comment: The Google Books preview confirms that it's actually in the book in that way. Their definition of sx is in [pixel/mm], evidently. @Megha: The values of sx and sy may be given by the camera manufacturer.

Comment: @JoseLuisBlanco sx = 10 pixel/mm, f = 35mm, then 
sx*f = 35mm * 10 pixel/mm = 350 pixels, it is not a division

Comment: @WhatAMesh Alright, I understood "sx" as the size of ONE pixel, that is, exactly the inverse of "sx = pixels per millimeter", which is its meaning in the answer above. With that definition, everything is correct. Good!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If your pixel is square shaped meaning physical width and height of the pixel are the same (e.g. 3.45x3.45 micron) then the fx = fy (e.g. fx = fy= 21000 pixels).

But if the pixel's width and height are different and the pixel is like a rectangle shape (e.g. 3.45x2.7 micron) then fx and fy will be different (e.g fx = 21000 pixels and fy = 18000 pixels ).