# camera coordinate to pixel coordinate opencv

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am confused about the opencv camera calibration coordinate transformation. I used the example code to calibrate my camera, and I got this result:

[image]

When I use this camera matrix to multiply a point in camera coordinate system, say P = [50, 50, 1.35], the output result is too big which is impossible to be a pixel coordinate. What's is wrong here ? Did I miss something ?

The image is 1920 x 1080. This is the chessboard configuration file information:

[image]

Comment: It is totally possible to project a point that will not be inside the image. You choose a ratio between X and Z (or Y and Z) that is very big. It is like I want to project a point that is 1.5 m away from the camera in Z but that is 50 m away in X and Y...

Comment: @Catree     I don't quite understand what you say by "You choose a ratio between X and Z (or Y and Z) that is very big. "

Comment: This post explain very well the process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299870/computing-x-y-coordinate-3d-from-image-point?rq=1

Comment: @DamianoDamiano, Thanks for the post. I understand's the process. But I cannot figure out why this multiplication fails to project P = [50, 50, 1.35] this point. I think something is missing.

Comment: There is no problem with the multiplication, you can find here more information in the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). Your point P is X=50, Y=50, Z=1.35 in the camera frame. The Z axis is going forward, the X axis is going to the right and the Y axis is going to the down. Now read again my analogy. Again, there is no need for a mathematically projected point in the camera frame to be inside the image. It is the same like a camera and your point P is not visible by the camera.

Comment: @Catree Thanks for your explanation. I understands now. Can you put it in the answer so that I can close this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find in the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) the different equations for the perspective projection model, also illustrated in the following pictures (thanks to this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96074/110561)).

[image: Camera model]

Assuming a point `P=(X,Y,Z)` in the camera frame `Fc`, its coordinate in the normalized camera frame is:

```
x' = X/Z
y' = Y/Z
```

And its projection onto the image plane (assuming no distortion):

```
u = fx * x' + cx
v = fy * y' + cy
```

With `fx` and `fy` the focal length in pixel and `cx`, `cy` the coordinate of the principal point in the image.

In your case, your Z is at 1.35 away from the camera but the 2 other coordinates are way too far compared to the Z coordinate.

There is no problem mathematically, it is just that your point P is not visible for your camera.

Comment: Exactly, you can also compute the theoretical field of view needed and you should get something like 177° (`2*atan(50/1.35)`).

Comment: is there any relation between `f` and `fx and fy` ? Assuming f = 1, should the equation be u = 1 * x' + cx ?

Comment: @infoclogged See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330470/6055233) or [here](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~afb/classes/CS4495-Fall2014/slides/CS4495-CameraModel.pdf) for more theoretical information.