# How to calculate Focal length in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Having an image pixels and a straight line selected on it (from pixel `[x_1, y_1]` to pixel `[x_2, y_2]`), how to get  Focal length in OpenCV (Python or C++; 2.4 or 3.x)?

Comment: You can get the focal length (in pixel) from camera calibration. Maybe you read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329867/why-does-the-focal-length-in-the-camera-intrinsics-matrix-have-two-dimensions) for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are need the

```
focal length
```

of camera,I think you should make
calibration and you will get a the

```
camera matrix
```

which contains the focal length.

here is a good documentation to camera calibration

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html